# I record daily contract price data in SQL. I need to avg a range of contracts such as 3-14, 13-24, etc. and group by codes, not rows, and settle date

Tags: sql

I haven't been able to figure this out or find any code to sample from that would group it properly. I can't average it by row because data gets appended every day so it needs to be the average Close Price of the range codes by Close Date.

From the data below, I would need to average the Close Price of Codes /GNG<2> to /GNG<13> (row 3-14), then average the Close Price of Codes /GNG<12> to /GNG<23> (rows 13-24 [not shown]), and so on through 5 years (grouped in 12 months) and have it grouped by the Close Date so that the output would look something like this:

```
 Year  Close  Close Date
  1    3.586  07/27/2021
  2    3.071  07/27/2021
  3    -----  07/27/2021
  4    -----  07/27/2021
  5    -----  07/27/2021

  1    3.496  07/28/2021
  2    3.021  07/28/2021
  3    -----  07/28/2021
  4    -----  07/28/2021
  5    -----  07/28/2021
```

[image]

```
select * 
,avg([close]) over(
partition by [close date]) as avgclose
from database
where [code] IN ('/GNG<2>','/GNG<3>','/GNG<4>','/GNG<5>','/GNG<6>','/GNG<7>','/GNG<8>','/GNG<9>','/GNG<10>','/GNG<11>','/GNG<12>','/GNG<13>')
```

This works but how can I get it to show the results as something like the table by year instead of individual contracts with the same avgclose on each one like the image?

**Here is this data that should be able to be pasted into Excel**

Row Code    Description Close   Close Date  Expiration Date Contract Date
1   /GNG<0> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (Front Month)    3.971   07/27/2021  07/28/2021  08/01/2021
2   /GNG<1> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (2nd Month)  3.942   07/27/2021  08/27/2021  09/01/2021
3   /GNG<2> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (3rd Month)  3.939   07/27/2021  09/28/2021  10/01/2021
4   /GNG<3> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (4th Month)  4.002   07/27/2021  10/27/2021  11/01/2021
5   /GNG<4> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (5th Month)  4.1 07/27/2021  11/26/2021  12/01/2021
6   /GNG<5> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (6th Month)  4.158   07/27/2021  12/29/2021  01/01/2022
7   /GNG<6> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (7th Month)  4.073   07/27/2021  01/27/2022  02/01/2022
8   /GNG<7> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (8th Month)  3.804   07/27/2021  02/24/2022  03/01/2022
9   /GNG<8> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (9th Month)  3.194   07/27/2021  03/29/2022  04/01/2022
10  /GNG<9> NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (10th Month) 3.108   07/27/2021  04/27/2022  05/01/2022
11  /GNG<10>    NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (11th Month) 3.136   07/27/2021  05/26/2022  06/01/2022
12  /GNG<11>    NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (12th Month) 3.172   07/27/2021  06/28/2022  07/01/2022
13  /GNG<12>    NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (13th Month) 3.179   07/27/2021  07/27/2022  08/01/2022
14  /GNG<13>    NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (14th Month) 3.164   07/27/2021  08/29/2022  09/01/2022
15  /GNG<14>    NYMEX Henry Hub Natural Gas Futures Electronic (15th Month) 3.183   07/27/2021  09/28/2022  10/01/2022

Comment: This might help it is a windows function avg(closeprice) over (partition by closedate)

Comment: This might help too: [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)